# Strange Regex Capture Group behavior returning "or" pipes into result

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to make a capture group to find/replace suffixes.

Please see the example here:

https://www.myregextester.com/?r=b23e74dc

and my summary below:

**Regex:**

```
(\b(.*?)(logical|logic))
```

**Requested Ouput:**

- 0=\0
- 1=\1
- 2=\2

however the output of the capture groups I test return the "|" into the result with it seems some redundancy

**Output:**

- 0=Meteorologic
- 1=Meteorologic
- 2=Meteoro0=|Meteorological
- 1=|Meteorological
- 2=|Meteoro

Clearly I have introduced some error into the regex since I do NOT want the "|" in the output but I am unclear what it could be.

Comment: There is no other solution *if* you need the 0th group. I can suggest re-using `\1` since it is placed around the whole pattern, but also consume the `|`: [`(([^|]*)(logic(?:al)?))\|?`](https://regex101.com/r/yX0oO3/1) and replace with `\n0=\1\n1=\1\n2=\2\n` (the newlines can be adjusted as per your needs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should lay it out so you can see it.

```
Meteorologic|Meteorological


0=Meteorologic
1=Meteorologic
2=Meteoro
0=|Meteorological
1=|Meteorological
2=|Meteoro
```

The first match ends `Meteorologic`|Meteorological

The second match starts Meteorologic`|Meteorological`

At between `c` and `|` is a word boundary, so `\b` is satisfied.

Then `.*?` (capture group 2) matches the `|Meteoro` up to logical.

Then `logical` in capture group 3.

So, it does what you requested.

---

**The fix**

*To bias the word boundary to find a word to the right, just introduce a

lookahead like this `(\b(?=\w)(.*?)(logical|logic))`*

---

A note about word boundaries: they are ambi-dexterous.

Equivalent to

```
 (?:
      (?:
           ^ 
        |  (?<= [^a-zA-Z0-9_] )
      )
      (?= [a-zA-Z0-9_] )
   |  
      (?<= [a-zA-Z0-9_] )
      (?:
           $ 
        |  (?= [^a-zA-Z0-9_] )
      )
 )
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negated pattern `[^|]*` to match anything but pipe:

```
(\b([^|]*)(logic(?:al)?))
```

Alternatively you can use `\w` as well:

```
(\b(\w*)(logic(?:al)?))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ5kD0/1)

Comment: Thanks but I thought the whole purpose of the pipe is that it is NOT matched and used as an "or" separator as per http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: Yes that is true pipe in `(logical|logic)` is indeed acting like an alternation. What you're seeing in captured group is a pipe that comes due to your use of `.*?` which captures everything in input before `logic` or logical and your input has a literal pipe character